# Altium: how to detect components not imported in layout?

Tags: altium

I'm looking for a way to detect components that are in the schematic but not in the layout.

Of course I can do a "design/ import", but I'm looking for something more like troubleshoot/alert at a late stage before sending to production.

What happened to me is that a component "disappeared" during a merge and as the only
operations done after the merge were aesthetic and exports, nobody saw it.

Typically, an option in DRC would be perfect. I found "difference report" in the output job but I'm looking for something more interactive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Project -> Show Differences menu option will show you differences between the PcbDoc and SchDoc.

For now there's no option in Altium to include difference checks in DRC.